# Filter join with attributes in a rich join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose I have these tables:

```
markets (id)
user_markets (user_id, market_id)
users (id)
```

and I'm able to reach a user's markets by an INNER JOIN with user_markets.

Now I add two more columns to `user_markets`: `price_above` and `price_below` and a column to `markets`: `last_price`

So now we have:

```
markets (id, last_price)
user_markets (user_id, market_id, price_above, price_below)
users (id)
```

My goal now is to fetch markets (for a user) of which the `markets.last_price` is either `>=` of the `price_above` and `<` of the `price_below` of the corresponding `user_markets` row.

I tried different things but apparently I always end up with the wrong result.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT m.*, u.* FROM markets m
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = um.user_id
INNER JOIN user_markets um ON um.market_id = m.id
WHERE m.last_price >= um.price_above OR m.last_price < um.price_below
```

Comment: I was about to post what I tried and this looks very similar, so perhaps my problem in the resultset can be something else. I'll try again in a few, thanks for the input!

Comment: indeed I wasn't filtering rows with price_above or price_below to 0, column default, so everything was returned, thanks